# how to ignore white space in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Using the code `[A-Z]+[.]` will select All-Caps words ending with a period. I was wondering how I would make this include an all-caps word behind it as well.

bold means it is the selected text

current: ASD **ASD.**

goal: **ASD ASD.**

Comment: `[A-Z ]+[.]` Just add `[ ]` to the character class. Or, `[A-Z\s]+[.]` but that will match vertical spaces (`\n`, `\r`) too

Comment: If you want to preclude the case of a leading white space, `/[A-Z][A-Z ]+[.]/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match either one or two words but no more you can make the second word optional with the `?` modifier:

```
(?:[A-Z]+\s+)?[A-Z]+\.
```

Or if you want to match as many words as there are before a period, you can use the `*` modifier instead:

```
(?:[A-Z]+\s+)*[A-Z]+\.
```

To obtain the index of the start of a match in JavsScript, you can do the following:

```
var regex = /(?:[A-Z]+\s+)?[A-Z]+\./;
var match = regex.exec('ASD ASD.');
console.log('The index of the first match is ' + match.index)
```

Comment: how would i get the start of each selection

Comment: What programming language are you using? Most modern programming languages offer ways to obtain the position of the start of a match.

Comment: i am using javascript

Comment: I just updated my answer with how you can obtain the index of the start of a match in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
/[A-Z ]+[.]/
```

Will do what you describe.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9boJk0/1/)

You can do `[A-Z\s]+[.]` but that matches `\n` too.

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/EIkgHI/1/)

Comment: This will match a string consisting of just a space and a period, however.